# C: integer from pointer without a cast in shunting yard implementation

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

I'm converting infix notation to reverse Polish notation. I need to compare the precedence of characters on the top of the stack to the next character in the string, `char *c`. The data in each node should point to a char. However, the line `int testResult = test(stack->head->data, c[i]);` is producing an error:

**error:** passing argument 1 of '**test**' makes integer from pointer without a cast.

How can this error be resolved (without modifying the structs)? What is wrong with passing `stack->head->data`? what should I be passing instead?

```
typedef struct Node
{
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} LinkedList;

typedef LinkedList Stack;

int precedence(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        ...
    }
}

int test(char a, char b) {
    int A = precedence(a);
    int B = precedence(b);
    ...
}

void function(char *c) {
     int i;
     Stack *stack = initialise_stack();

     for (i = 0; i < strlen(expr); i++) {
         int testResult = test(stack->head->data, c[i]);
         ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: `stack->head->data` is a void pointer, while the `test(char, char)` expects  char types.

Comment: I've tried messing around with various casts so that I can pass a char to `test`, but I can't get it to work. Can you suggest any way of modifying the code?

Comment: what does `stack->head->data` point to?  Is it a character?  Is it a string? another struct?  Generally speaking, your approach will be to cast `stack->head->data` to the appropriate pointer type, dereference that, and get the character to be tested in whatever way is appropriate to the type of thing that the dereference yields.

Comment: Well, the question here is really to you: what is `void *data` and why are you trying to pass it to a function that expect a `char`? It is not possible to meaningfully "modify the code" without knowing exactly what `data` is.

Comment: I'm pushing characters from the string `char *c` onto the stack, in this fashion: `push_stack(stack, &c[i], sizeof(char));`. Therefore, the data in each node should be a character.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `stack->head->data` is a pointer to `char`, this will work:

```
 int testResult = test(*(char*)stack->head->data, c[i]);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the error message is still the same.

Comment: Are you sure? You can not get "without a cast" error, when you're casting it.
Maybe error goes to different line? Something must change